# Downside of multiple indices on delayed inserts? - MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, insert, indexing, delay

I know that the downside of indices is that they have to be updated every time the table is written to - i.e affecting loading times. However, for one of my tables I frequently `SELECT` using 3 different columns in the `WHERE` clause. So I thought to myself, do I really want to add 3 indices to the table? The downside as before is the updating of each index on each write. However, the table is only written to using `INSERT DELAYED`. Does this mean there is no downside and I should use 3 indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you probably want one index with all 3 columns in it. MySQL can use only one index per table in a query.
There is a performance downside from having the index but it is a lot less than the downside from not having it.

Comment: If I add an index for 3 columns, but a query only uses 2 of those columns in the `WHERE` clause, does it still use the index? Does it matter in which order the columns are placed in the index?

Comment: Only if they are the first 2 columns in the index. Yes the order matters, if you want to use the x-th column in a given index you also have to use all the ones before x (1,2,3....x). You can make several indexes to cover all your cases.